# Xcode 7.2 can't find c++ std::pair

Tags: c++11, xcode7

First of all, I use Xcode 7.2 on OSX 10.11.2. In my main.cpp file, the std library is working fine. But, whenever I try to use it in any other c++ file, I get `unexpected unqualified-id`.

I have the following files :

```
main.cpp (std is working in it)

algo.hpp (std is not working in it)

algo.cpp (std is not working in it)
```

Why is the deployment target OSX 10.11 not finding the standard c++ library in all my files ?

Here is for exemple my header file algo.hpp

```
#ifndef algo_hpp
#define algo_hpp

std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> pgcdFB(const int m,const int n);

std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> euclide(const int m, const int n);

unsigned int fibonacci(const unsigned int i);

#endif /* algo_hpp */
```

On each line where I use std I get `undeclared identifier 'std`

Comment: Can you show the lines of code that's not working, and the exact error you're getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to include the proper headers, you simply forgot `#include <utility>`  since you're using `std::pair`. (and there seems to be no reason to include stdio.h here)